# Multiply two elements (columns e.g. quantity * unitPrice = enteredGrossAmount) in mat-table [dataSource] using reactive forms

Tags: angular

Do you have any idea on how to do it in Angular Reactive forms using Mat-Table and a Datasource
"Multiply two elements (columns e.g. quantity * unitPrice = enteredGrossAmount) in mat-table [dataSource] using reactive forms"

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="direction: rtl">
                    <h6><b>Quantity</b></h6>
                  </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element " [formGroup]="element">
                    <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="none" style="text-align: right">
                      <input #quantity matInput type="text" matInput placeholder="" formControlName="quantity" autocomplete="off" appOnlyNumber>
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="unitPrice">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="direction: rtl">
                    <h6><b>Unit Price</b></h6>
                  </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element " [formGroup]="element">
                    <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="none" style="text-align: right">
                      <input matInput  formControlName="unitPrice" autocomplete="off"
                      id="digit-only-decimal"
                      type="text"
                      digitOnly
                      decimal="true"
                      placeholder="0.00"
                      pattern="[0-9]+([\.][0-9]+)?">
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="enteredGrossAmount">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="direction: rtl">
                    <h6><b>Gross Amount</b></h6>
                  </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element " [formGroup]="element">
                    <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="none" style="text-align: right">
                      <input matInput type="text" matInput placeholder="" formControlName="enteredGrossAmount" autocomplete="off">
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
```

these are tha parts of my componets releated to formgrou and form array
    FormGroup

```
billingRegisterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [null],
    billDate: [new Date(), [Validators.required]],
    currencyRate: [{ value: this.decimalPipe.transform(0, '1.2-2'), disabled: true }],
    description1: [null, [Validators.required]],
    enteredAmount: [{ value: this.decimalPipe.transform(0, '1.2-2'), disabled: true }],
    documentTypeId: [null, [Validators.required]],
    sequenceNo: [null, [Validators.required]],
    creditTermId: [null, [Validators.required]],
    currencyId: [null, [Validators.required]],
    customerId: [null, [Validators.required]],
    taxClassId: [null, [Validators.required]],
    active: [{ value: true, disabled: true }],
    registerDetails: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });

     FormaArray

onAddRegisterDetail() {

    this.billingRegisterArray = <FormArray>this.billingRegisterForm.get('registerDetails');
    const grp = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [null],
      quantity: [1, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.min(1)]],
      unitPrice: [0.00, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.mobnumPattern)]],
      enteredGrossAmount: [{ value: 0.00, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      discountRate: [0.00, Validators.required],
      enteredDiscountAmount: [{ value: 0.00, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      enteredNetAmount: [{ value: 0.00, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      description1: [null, Validators.required],
      flexFieldCombinationId: ['', Validators.required],
      uomId: [null, Validators.required],
      taxClassId: [null, Validators.required]
    });
    this.billingRegisterArray.push(grp);
    this.billingRegisterForm.setControl('registerDetails', this.billingRegisterArray);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource((
      this.billingRegisterForm.get('registerDetails') as FormArray).controls);
  }



<ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
                      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="direction: rtl">
                        <h6><b>Delete</b></h6>
                      </mat-header-cell>
                      <mat-cell class="text-center" *matCellDef="let element ; let i = index">
                        <button type="button"  horizontal-align: right mat-icon-button color="warn"
                          (click)="onDelete(i)" [disabled]="this.buttonDisable">
                          <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color':'warning'}" class="mat-18">delete</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                      </mat-cell>>
                    </ng-container>
```

Comment: can you show the component code where you build the form? is it a form array? or just an array of form groups as the data source?

Comment: hi bryan60, just added the code related to formgroup and formarry..thanks thanks

Comment: can things be deleted from the array? can you show that code if it exists?

Comment: Yes, rows can be deleted

Comment: then the answer i posted will have some free hanging subscriptions, but they'll get cleaned up when the component gets destroyed, or you could try to get clever and unsubscribe when the control is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're gona want to do is in your add function, subscribe to the `valueChanges` of the controls involved and use that to set the value of the control you want.

```
onAddRegisterDetail() {

    this.billingRegisterArray = <FormArray>this.billingRegisterForm.get('registerDetails');
    const grp = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [null],
      quantity: [1, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.min(1)]],
      unitPrice: [0.00, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.mobnumPattern)]],
      enteredGrossAmount: [{ value: 0.00, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      discountRate: [0.00, Validators.required],
      enteredDiscountAmount: [{ value: 0.00, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      enteredNetAmount: [{ value: 0.00, disabled: true }, Validators.required],
      description1: [null, Validators.required],
      flexFieldCombinationId: ['', Validators.required],
      uomId: [null, Validators.required],
      taxClassId: [null, Validators.required]
    });

    // get the controls
    const quantityCtrl = grp.get('quantity');
    const priceCtrl = grp.get('unitPrice');
    const grossAmtCtrl = grp.get('enteredGrossAmount');
    // combine value changes, start one with initial value
    combineLatest(
      quantityCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(quantityCtrl.value)), 
      priceCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(priceCtrl.value)) // may need to coerce type with map
    ).subscribe(([quantity, unitPrice]) => grossAmtCtrl.setValue(quantity * unitPrice)) // may need to format

    this.billingRegisterArray.push(grp);

    // you should only set the control and data source once
    // this.billingRegisterForm.setControl('registerDetails', this.billingRegisterArray);
    // this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource((
      this.billingRegisterForm.get('registerDetails') as FormArray).controls);
}
```

this should be safe and not cause memory leaks as it's all local and should garbage collect ok, but if you want to be safe, add some controller property like:

```
private grossAmtSubs: Subscription[] = []
```

and push the subscriptions to it:

```
this.grossAmtSubs.push(
  combineLatest(
    ...
  ).subscribe( ... )
);
```

and add an `ngOnDestroy` hook to unsubscribe.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.grossAmtSubs.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe())
}
```

this will guarantee no memory leaks and is good practice, but should be safe either way.

also, if you have some delete item function, you could try and unsubscribe there too...

```
onDelete(i: index) {
  const registerDetails = <FormArray>this.billingRegisterForm.get('registerDetails');
  registerDetails.removeAt(i);
  this.grossAmtSubs[i].unsubscribe();
  this.grossAmtSubs.splice(i,1);

}
```

edit... if you want to sum, subscribe to the array value changes somewhere like...

```
this.billingRegisterForm.get('registerDetails').valueChanges.pipe(
  map(values => values.reduce((total, value) => total += value.enteredGrossAmount, 0)),
  distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe(total => console.log('do whatever with the total: ', total))
```

Comment: Hi bryan60, your code really works, by the way, I'm sorry but I forgot to ask on how to get the sum of my formarray (enteredGrossAmount), appreciate your response. thanks!

Comment: added something for the array sum